# What is the reason behind Sri Ahobila Mutt having two acharya parampara branches?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, vadakalai, vedanta-desika

[Ahobila mutt](http://www.ahobilamutt.org/us/home/welcome.asp) is a prominent muth in the [Vadakalai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Vaishnavism#Vadakalais_.28.22northern.22.29_-_Vedanta_Desika) sect of Sri Vaishnava tradition. The exponder of this sect is [Sriman Vedanta desika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta_Desika).  Acharya Lineage(parampara) is one of the important characteristics of Sri Vaishnava tradition.

Ahobila Mutt has two different lineages. The branches are listed as Samasrayana Parampara and Kalakshepa Parampara with the acharya lineage branching after Swami Bhashyakarar. Click [here](http://www.ahobilamutt.org/us/acharya/lineage/lineage.asp) for reference.

- What are samashrayana parampara and Kalakshepa parampara?
- What is the reason behind two different lineages?

Comment: Well Samshrayana parampara acharyas would be the one who don't believe in necessity of Bharasamarpanam, because Samshranyanam is pancha samskram given at the time of initiation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samasrayana . Thenkalai sect believes that Samhrayanam is all that is needed for Prapatti but Vadakalai people think that explicit act of surrender is necessary i.e, Bharasamarpanam or Bharanasyam.

Comment: I also noticed that the two Paramparas are merged again from Srimad Athivan Satakopa Yatindra Mahadesikan onwards.
Notably, from his successor onwards the title of Srimad Azhagiya Singar has been conferred to the Madathipathi

Comment: So they are merged to become one sect like before split?!!!! What is Madathipathi?

Comment: @Yogi yes they split into two paramparas but now the same person is Madathipathi(head of the Mutt) for both.

Comment: Wow thats unusual and weird how can he initiate people into thenakalai and vadakali sects both?? What are their taniyans?

Comment: @Yogi I too am interested to know more!

Comment: If what you are saying is correct then the difficult decision of choosing subsect would be elemenated.

Comment: @Yogi Sorry, my previous response should have been more nuanced, i am not sure if the madathipathi wields power to initiate into both sects. And even if he does so, there will surely be conditions demanded of the initiate that can potentially differ! I merely stated historical aspect that is readily verifiable in the question.

Comment: It is interesting to observe how several of the Acharyas in the Samasrayanam Paramparai belong to the Thennacharya sampradayam, and also how Vedanta Desikan does not occupy a position in this Paramparai. One accepted view among both kalais is that the Muttam may have started as a Tenkalai Muttam, with connections to Acharya Purushas giving it Samasrayanam rights. It became Vadakalai with the patronage and support of the Vijayanagaram Empire.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to give a clear picture about what are the origins of the Ahobila mutt. It is a religious institution formed at the end of the 14th century by Srimad Aadivan Satakopa Yateendra mahadesika. He was born in the year 1379 in the prestigious Athreya gothra to a great scholar who lived in Thirunarayanapuram (Melkote) called Keshavachar. He was named Srinivasa and underwent the samasrayana under his father who hails from the parampara where after Ramanuja.

The following chain of acharya could be seen: Embar-Bhattar-Nanjeeyar-Nampillai-VadakkuThiruveethiPillai-Srirangachar (father of the great grandfather of adivan satkopa)-his son Keshavachar-his son Srinivasachar-his son Kesavachar (who is the father and samasrayanaacharya of adivan satakopa).

At this point you should note that the parampara is the same as the parampara of swami manavala mamunigal (who himself got the preshamanthropadesha, a mantra for initiating into the sanyasashrma, from adivan satakopa).

Sri rangachar who is a distan relative of swami desika's guru kidambi Appular, followed the vadakala tradition. But he got his samasrayanam under vadakku Thiruveethipillai, since it is his choice as to whom to opt as his acharya and also there were no differences in sects till 17th century.

Therefore it cannot be taken that adivan satakopa swamy was a thenkalai and that he changed to vadakalai. Then he was sent study higher adhyatmic studies under ghatikasatham ammal, who hails from the lineage of vedanta desika, therefore having desika in his kalakshepa parampara. Then at the age of 21 he renounced all materialistic practices and got sanyasa from Lord Narasimha of the Ahobila Himself. Then on started the holy monastic organization under the order of swamy lakshmi narasimha and srimad aadi van satakopa yateendra mahadesika which follows the vadakali sect.

Unlike one said that ahobila mutt has attachments with both the sects, the ahobila mutt has more authority in the vadakalai sect. But there are inscriptions that all descendants of the 74 simhasanadhipathis approached swami for acharyathvam. I also want to mention something here is that vadakalai sect is not a lately formed sect as it existed even when thenkalai sect started. Therefore any confusions regarding this are severely misleading thank yo
Aadivan satakopaagnya vardhatham abhivardhtham

Comment: This looks odd to read. Split your answer into some paragraphs, use appropriate [formatting tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help) available and cite some sources.

Comment: @Pandya How can a new user know how to edit according to markdown when users who write many answers wrote? There should be some help from our side. Like adding some help center links for editing.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Thanks for pointing out, just added link in the comment. Btw, I've just found a meta post discussing similar issue.